# Named capture groups in vim regex?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, find

Does vim allow us to assign names to capture groups for search/replace that can be used in place of `\1`, `\2` etc... for back-references and substitution?

Like in in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="ABCD HELLO, WORLD! 1234"
>>> print(re.sub(r"^(?P<foo>\w+).*?(?P<bar>\d+)$", r"\n\g<foo> \g<bar>\n", s))

ABCD 1234
```

Or Perl:

```
dade_murphy@darkstar$ \
> printf "ABCD HELLO, WORLD! 1234" \
>   | perl -pe 's/^(?<foo>\w+).*?(?<bar>\d+)$/\n$+{foo} $+{bar}\n/'

ABCD 1234
```

ie. something like this:

```
:s/^\(?P<foo>\w\+\)\s*$/\g<foo>/
```

Neither syntax seems to work. I'm guessing this is not supported-- it doesn't strike me as a feature that would be particularly sought after in a text editor. But search / Google aren't confirming either way, so here I am.

Comment: Idk about named captures, but numbered, yes. See `help \1` i believe.

Comment: Note possible. It has been requested years ago but was never implemented.

Comment: Capture groups are possible. Why would you want a named capture groups?

Comment: one potential advantage to named groups is the ability to have more than 9 (if implemented that way)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was thinking specifically about the user defined variety. I updated the question to make that more explicit.

Comment: @jdhao There are a few good reasons. First is the limitation @Mass mentioned (although if you really need more than 9 regex capture groups in a text editor, you probably belong in a padded room). If you have multiple groups being referenced by `\1`, `\2`, etc... then adding/removing groups will shift those indexes and you'll need to adjust any references. Named groups prevent that problem. Last, it can make it a little easier to read (i wanted to use `\g<SPACES>` instead of `\1`, for example)

Comment: @Mass one of the first patches I made for Vim were to move the limit from 9 capture groups to 99 groups. That was almost 10 years ago. It has never been merged (but rather we got a new second regexp engine :(). Back then I was working with CSV files quite often and that patch would have been very helpful, but oh well...

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt very interesting.  Is that patch online still?  I looked for a little bit and couldn't find it, except for the mention in the todo

Comment: @Mass It's still available in the archive of vim-dev: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/w6cA_ueF7BY/WkCxVgsrErIJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, named capture groups are not available.

In fact, some design decisions in Vim actually expose the limit of 9 (numbered) capture groups, such as the [`matchlist()` function](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#matchlist%28%29), which returns a list of 10 strings for each of `\0` through `\9`. (That doesn't mean named groups would be impossible, it's just exposing some internals showing this is quite an ingrained design decision.)

You can also go through the whole [`:help pattern-searches`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html) and you'll see no reference to named capture groups.

Vim also has some regexp features (namely `\zs` and `\ze` to mark the start and end of the match) that can replace the use of capture groups and are often more convenient to use in case you're only using capture groups to repeat them as part of the replacement.

So, in short, no, named capture groups are not available as of Vim 8.1.

Comment: Darn it! Oh well, kind of what I was expecting, but it's good to have it confirmed. Good answer, and thanks for the extra insights!